# Can we make the link to the homepage a different colour in the chat window

Tags: feature-request, design

You may have noticed a link to the biology SE homepage when in the chat, but then again probably not, because it's near invisible!

[image]

Could we change the colour of the green parts to make it visible please - suggest using the same colours as in the homepage header logo.

[image]

Comment: well spotted @madscientist

Comment: This is clearly a well planned example of crypsis meticulously crafted by the designers. Bravo!